# Ionic 5 Angular Tabs static display

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

With the `ion-tab` element *replaced* by `ion-tab-bar` & Angular Routing (as documented in the [breaking changes](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#angular-tabs)) - is there another way of displaying "static tabs"?

The routing/lazy loading is great for certain scenarios, but not when I want to share my object between tabs.
The [Usage Docs for JavaScript](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs) still show the usage of `ion-tab`, which would work perfectly for me. Something like this:

```html
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab tab="tab-schedule">
    Static content {{foo.schedule}}
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab tab="tab-speaker">
    Static content {{foo.speaker}}
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-schedule">
      <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-speaker">
      <ion-label>Speakers</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Is there another way I can accomplish this behaviour in Ionic 5 Angular?

Comment: Hi @JvR did you find a solution ? I'm trying to do the same thing like you. Thx

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. Have you tried the below `ion-segment` suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no way to use ion-tabs without routing. I've tried a few attempts and failed. For static tabs, Ionic offers the `ion-segment` component, which is used like this:

```
      <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSegment">
        <ion-segment-button value="1">
          <ion-label>1</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>

        <ion-segment-button value="2">
          <ion-label>2</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>

      </ion-segment>


      <div *ngIf="1 === selectedSegment">
        1
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="2 === selectedSegment">
        2
      </div>
```

The docs are here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment